# Best strategy to build custom batch search engine?

Tags: perl, batch-file, search-engine

Hi I need to build a site similar to indeed.com and so many others, that tracks a number of advertising sites and parses the HTML to list the ads in my own site.

I know that each source-site needs a particular strategy. That's no problem. My concern is that I want to scan the sites hourly in a batch-fashion.

Is there a better suitable strategy to accomplish this? I've been told that Perl is a very strong batch scripting language .. Is it so?? How do I start?

Best,

Comment: Google have me this: http://www.cs.utk.edu/cs594ipm/perl/crawltut.html

Answer (score 2):

The good news is, you can do this in Perl.  The bad news is that this going to complex.  Just like it would be in any language.

Start by reading [Learning Perl](http://books.google.com/books?id=4pINCzVk9NMC&lpg=PP1&dq=Learning%20Perl&client=safari&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Next you'll need to put together your spidering code.

Start with a simple single script that reads one page at a time.

There are many modules for getting webpages.  Which to use depends on your needs.  It gets even more complex if you need to scrape Javascript generated page.  Start with LWP::Simple or WWW::Mechanize.  You can expand from there.

There are also many modules for parsing HTML.  HTML::Treebuilder is a powerful module that has worked very well for me.

Once you can reliably download and parse a single page, you will need to add the spidering logic.  Next you have to decide how you want to traverse the site--breadth or depth first?  Are you going to go with a recursive alogorithm? Or perhaps a procedural approach?

If you are scanning many pages you need to scan, you may need to create a controller to manage multiple spiders.  You could use Coro, AnyEvent, POE, threads, or a `fork` based strategy to manage your workers.  What you choose will depend on your needs.

You can use the DBI module with the appropriate driver (eg DBD::MySQL) to insert the data in your database.

All you have to do now is generate your web app.  There are many toolkits of various levels of complexity and power available.  CGI::Application and Catalyst are two popular libraries.  HTML::Mason and Squatting are some other options.

All of the modules I listed are available on CPAN.  Used appropriately, CPAN will save you a lot of work.  For many tasks the problem is too many choices, rather than a lack of them.

The book is, of course, available anywhere books are sold.